# Display text below an image without causing a break HTML

Tags: html, image, text

Basically I want to put some text below an image but without causing a break in lines for the next image
Here is what I have right now
Basically the images have to stay next to each other automatically like they do by default but each image under it needs to have text.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Card Tracker V1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .img_div { float: left; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="img_div">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" width="100" />
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="img_div">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" width="100" />
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </div>
        <div class="img_div">
            <img src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" width="100" />
            <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ignore `width` attribute of `img`. That's just because my sample is big.

[image]

Comment: It works great, thanks! Sorry I'm just now learning html haha, I have a small question so maybe you can answer it instead of me making a new post (And to make sure it works with yours) how can I make a small amount of space between the images?There was space between it before but now its gone.

Comment: Add `margin-right: 10px` to `img_div` class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
<figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
<img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
<figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
<img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
<figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
<img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
<figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
<img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
<figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
```

CSS:

```
img{display:block}
```

Comment: No that still makes them all go in a vertical line, I need all the images next to each other but all the text below the image they go with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, figcaption is supposed to go inside a figure element.

You'll probably want to add a float left to get them to float.

```css
figure {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
  <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
  <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
  <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
  <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
  <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating groups of image and text using container tag like `div`

```
<div>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</div>
<div>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</div>
<div>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</div>
<div>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</div>
<div>
    <img src='./Tarmogoyf.png'>
    <figcaption>You have 0 Tarmogoyf cards.</figcaption>
</div>
```

CSS will be:

```
.img-container{float:left; margin:5px}
.img-container .img{display:block;}
```

You can also specify height and width to image to get same sized thumbnails

Comment: If all my images will be the same size do I still need to do that?

Comment: @128Gigabytes If your images are of same size then no need of specifying width...But if you give height and width to div it will give you additional layout stability and layout wont get distracted